# How can I see what variables are sent from flash to a PHP script?

Tags: php, flash, forms, redirect, scripting

I was wondering how I could see what variables my flash sends to my PHP script. Is that possible? Maybe an extension or something else? I don't know if my flash is sending any variables.

My problem is that I have a flash which I can't change and the flash has a form. In that form the variables are sent to a PHP script. We had to move that script and now I made a redirect script which was working great with the webform(html_ but not with the flash form. Does anyone have some ideas about how I could fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As as using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for [viewing HTTP requests](http://getfirebug.com/net.html) inside Firefox, also check out [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), a proxy app which sits between your browser and the Internet and shows you detailed information about every HTTP request.

Comment: Another option is to store the output from `var_dump`ing `$_GET` and `$_POST`, but I'd go with Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Use the firebug plugin with FireFox

Comment: how can i see the variables with firebug

Comment: to see what is passed to the server use the "Net" tab, there u can see all the hits being made and the GET/POST datain those hits